# Threejs: Draw elbow with begin radius and end radius

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js

I'm new to Threejs. I'm trying to draw an elbow with different `begin_radius` and `end_radius` along a curve path with the `curve_radius` and an `angle`, however couldn't achieve results.

- `CylinderGeometry` have `begin_radius` and `end_radius` but doesn't have curve path
- `TorusGeometry` have `curve_radius` and `angle` but doesn't have `begin_radius` and `end_radius`, as well as it is not solid.
- `LatheGeometry` had same limitation as `CylinderGeometry`
- `ExtrudeGeometry` had same limitation as `TorusGeometry`
- `TubeGeometry` had same limitation as `TorusGeometry`

Probably I'm overlooking the above geometries. Please guide some approach.

**--EDIT: June 1 2020--**

https://jsfiddle.net/arundhaj/ysfr8jb0
I've somehow managed to extend `TubeGeometry` to achieve the variable radius. However still couldn't able to make it solid. 
I've taken `generateCap` function from `CylinderGeomery` to add cap at the beginning and end of the arc. It works fine when I add only one cap, however if I add both the cap, shape is getting distorted.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Implemented by extending `TorusGeometry` https://jsfiddle.net/arundhaj/7cs9kvrj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my mind, I think the best solution would be to customize a thorus geometry to have at least the `begin_radius` and `end_radius` parameters.

What you could do is take the [original file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/geometries/TorusGeometry.js) and replace the static `radius` argument by a gradient definition in there :

> ```
> for ( j = 0; j <= radialSegments; j ++ ) {
>
>       for ( i = 0; i <= tubularSegments; i ++ ) {
>
>           var u = i / tubularSegments * arc;          
>           var v = j / radialSegments * Math.PI * 2;
>
>           // vertex
>
>           vertex.x = ( radius + tube * Math.cos( v ) ) * Math.cos( u );
>           vertex.y = ( radius + tube * Math.cos( v ) ) * Math.sin( u );
>           vertex.z = tube * Math.sin( v );
>
>           vertices.push( vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z );
>
>           // normal
>
>           center.x = radius * Math.cos( u );          
>           center.y = radius * Math.sin( u );          
>           normal.subVectors( vertex, center ).normalize();
>
>           normals.push( normal.x, normal.y, normal.z );
>
>           // uv
>
>           uvs.push( i / tubularSegments );            
>           uvs.push( j / radialSegments );
>
>       }
>
>   }
> ```

The remaining problem would just be to understand how to increase properly the right parameters, you'd have to test a bit to understand which parameters you need to change.

Comment: I've tried your approach too https://jsfiddle.net/arundhaj/7cs9kvrj/ however, still trying to make it look solid by adding cap to top and bottom.

Comment: You could just create a CircleGeometry object with the good radius (beginning radius at one end, endRadius at the other), calculate the position of the center of the circle at both ends to move it here from the center of your custom tubegeometry, and rotate by Math.PI/2 around the right axis to create the cap.

Comment: I would do that if I were you, but more precisely I would create a new THREE.Group, creat an object from your custom TubeGeometry, and create both caps separately with circle geometries and the same material as the tubeGeometry, then move them to the right place